# I can implement icomoon icons with onsen ui?

Tags: onsen-ui

I watched icomoon, and you can see that I can create my own icons, and down I can use with osenui but only if you use the tag `class=<icon>`
And I realized I dare ui works with `<ons-icon icon=<icon>`, and can be configured to `icon=<>` work with icomoon?

I tried the following

```
<ons-icon icon="icon-icomoon"></ons-icon> //this does not help me
```

if I change class, if I work

```
 <ons-icon class="icon-icomoon"></ons-icon>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't easily do it using the `icon` attribute but as you've discovered it works if you set the class. However I don't think the `size` attribute will work.

The `icon` attribute is a custom attribute and it doesn't do anything if the value doesn't start with "ion-" or "fa-".

The other attributes are defined using pure CSS so they should work regardless though.

You can check how it's done here:
https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/master/framework/directives/icon.js